# Jenkins PhpUnit – CodeCoverage problems

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, code-coverage

I work on a project with multiple Class and methods, and I want to use **PhpUnit** for test each case and prevent problems with a tool named **Jenkins**. (Server monitoring)

The purpose of this tool is to have a view on **code coverage**. I can see where PhpUnit went during suite Test.

But I do not think CodeCoverage *goes everywhere* in my Class and Methods.

Example :

```
Class Class1Test {
    Public method1 ( $inputs )  {
        $var = Class3::setVar();
        Return Class2 :: Method1 ( $inputs, $var ) ;
    }
} 

Class Class2 {
    Public static method2 ( $inputs, $var ) {
        Echo ‘’ hi there ! $inputs ‘’ ;
    }
}
```

So when I test with PhpUnit like :

```
Class Test extends PhpUnit… {
    …
    testmethod2( ) {
        $this->assertNotEmpty( $inputs ) ;
    }
}
```

The codeCoverage **don’t cover** my Class2 : Method1 in the codeCoverage.
Of course it’s small example here, in my project I got much more imbrication of Class and Methods and the CodeCoverage cover only the class and method calling in the Test File.

**Is there a way to consider all my method with one test ?**

Thank you very **mush** for your help.

EDIT ***

Here my phpunit.xml :

```
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/3.7/phpunit.xsd"
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="src/TJS/bootstrap.php"
    cacheTokens="true"
    colors="true"

    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="false"

    forceCoversAnnotation="false"
    mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
    printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"

    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    strict="false"
    verbose="true"

    checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="false"
    >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="TJS">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">src/TJS/_tests_unit/classes/</directory>
            <!--<directory suffix="Test.php">tests/integration/</directory>-->
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>        

    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src/TJS/classes</directory>        
        </whitelist>
    </filter>        


    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-crap4j" target="build/logs/crap4j.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"  />
    </logging> 
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the methods, so there is no coverage.
But I think I know what you mean. By default, the code coverage report does not include any classes for each there is no execution, so you don't have them in the coverage report and your coverage percent seems higher. To fix this add in the phpunit.xml

```
<filter>
      <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">../app</directory>
      </whitelist>
</filter>
```

(this assumes that your application is in ./app and your phpunit.xml is in ./tests for example)

Comment: Yes you understood my problem, I edited my post and I added my phpunit.xml, but this not working. The code coverage only concerns the Test of where the Test need to go ? (Sorry if my explains are wrong)